# Guidelines for providing large downloads in IIS + ASP.NET (MVC)

Tags: asp.net, iis, download, large-files

We want to allow users to download large files from our ASP.NET MVC2 system.

We are providing the files through the `Controller.File` method, which streams from `FileStream` to `Response.OutputStream`.
The reason we use `Controller.File` instead of providing a direct link is that we need to verify security rules on the logged in (Forms authentication) user.

What would be the largest areas of concern when doing this?

- **Security**: we'll probably need to increase executionTimeout. Does this expose security issues?
- **Memory**: I assume that, since Controller.File is streaming the contents directly from disk, there are little memory implications.
- **CPU**: I read on various blogs that providing large downloads is heavy on the cpu, but these were unconfirmed statements, so I did not find any recommendations from MS.
- **Network**: how many concurrent downloads are possible? Can we throttle, so that other traffic is not hindered by this?
- **Other**?

What would be your recommendations?

What would be other options than going through the ASP.NET pipeline, but still provides us with the data we need to validate the logged in user. ISAPI is said to reduce CPU and Memory, maybe some other advantages here?

Are there any (official) guidelines or best practices available concerning this?

Comment: I have the same requirements. Did you ever find a good solution for this? could you answer this question yourself now? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would look to do it asynchronously. Make sure buffering is switched off, that way your data is sent to the client rather than asp waiting for you to finish. if you're already streaming, then that's a good thing. I'm assuming you mean you read x bytes from the filestream and write those bytes to the output stream, repeat until EOF.

I'm not aware of any guidelines I can point you at. The above come from my own experience.